# Which correlation to use to measure how well 2 variables move together in the same direction?

Tags: correlation, mathematical-statistics

There are different types of correlation. Pearson, Kendall, Spearman and perhaps more which I am not aware of. I have 2 variables x and y. I want to measure how well these 2 variables move together in the same direction. Moving together means when x goes up, y goes up and when x goes down, y goes down. I do not care if these 2 variables move together linearly or non-linearly. The important measure is that they move together.

Which type of correlation should I use for such a measure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about linearity, you should use Spearman correlation, which is basically a normalized version of the difference in rank of the elements in your two vectors. This means any monotonic increasing function has a Spearman correlation of 1. If you do care about linearity, though, I recommend you use Pearson correlation (which is the most common too).

An example of this in R for an increasing function:

```
> x <- seq(-10,10,0.1)
> y <- 1/(1+exp(-x)) # Sigmoid function
> plot(x,y)
> cor(x,y) # Pearson, which is the most common
[1] 0.9361378
> cor(x,y, method='pearson') # Just to be sure
[1] 0.9361378
> cor(x,y, method='spearman')
[1] 1
```

Now a decreasing function:

```
> y <- 1-1/(1+exp(-x)) # Sigmoid function
> plot(x,y)
> cor(x,y, method='pearson')
[1] -0.9361378
> cor(x,y, method='spearman')
[1] -1
```